# HDD not showing up in Xubuntu

Tags: hard-drive, xubuntu, fstab

I am having some real issues trying to make my extra hard disks show up in Thunar.  I have edited fstab but I can only see them as root.  It's playing havoc with my auto backup as I have to remember to do it as root each time.
They appear to mount ok but just don't show up. my fstab entry for the drive is:

```
UUID=ac4c4b9d-4f81-48d9-8674-a57d9c72549a /media/hdd2   ext4  rw, auto, users, sync 0  2
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed!

It seems it was an ownership thing and to fix it I chowned the mount point and recursive directories from root to me using `sudo chown -hR mick:mick /media/sdc1`.

`/etc/fstab` needed no changes.

It has been no trouble since.  Don't you just love the internet for solving problems!